# Pandas Groupby with Agg Min/Max date

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the min/max dates from columns that might not have a date.

I have tried things like '', "NaN", True, False, 0, etc...

I first set the 'p_date' and 's_date' from the actual date based on the action of '+' or '-'.

```
 df_td [ 'p_date' ] = np.where ( df_td.action == '+', df_td.date, ??? )
 df_td [ 's_date' ] = np.where ( df_td.action == '-', df_td.date, ??? )
```

So I need the min of the p_date & max of the s_date here.

```
  issue      p_date      s_date
0  issue  2012-11-01            
1  issue  2013-12-09            
2  issue  2014-12-08            
3  issue              2016-01-13
4  issue  2012-11-01            
5  issue              2014-03-26
6  issue              2015-05-29
7  issue  2013-12-18            
8  issue              2016-01-13
```

I do a group by

```
g = df_td.groupby ( [ 'name', 'type' ], as_index = False ).agg (
     {  ...
        'p_date': 'min',
        's_date': 'max'
      } )
```

This gives me the following error.

```
'<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

if I make up a date for the blank space it does work but this is not a great option.

What can I fill the date with to get it to work?

Thanks.

Comment: This is question is unclear.. can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: You say you tried `"NaN"`, but the way you describe it makes it seem like you used a string with those three letters.  Did you try `NaN`, as in `np.nan` or `float("nan")`?

Comment: yes, tried both the Nan and the np.nan.  I think it is looking for a date object to work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas, `NaN` is used as the missing value, and is ignored for most operations, so it's the right one to use.  If you're still getting an error, it's probably because you've got a datetime.date there (well, you've definitely got that there, I mean that it's probably causing the problems).

For example, if your missing values are `""` and your column dtypes are `object` with internal types of `datetime.date`, I get:

```
In [496]: df.groupby("issue").agg({"p_date": "min", "s_date": "max"})
[...]
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

but if I switch to pandas-native time objects and NaNs, it works:

```
In [500]: df["p_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["p_date"])

In [501]: df["s_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["s_date"])

In [502]: df
Out[502]: 
   issue     p_date     s_date
0  issue 2012-11-01        NaT
1  issue 2013-12-09        NaT
2  issue 2014-12-08        NaT
3  issue        NaT 2016-01-13
4  issue 2012-11-01        NaT
5  issue        NaT 2014-03-26
6  issue        NaT 2015-05-29
7  issue 2013-12-18        NaT
8  issue        NaT 2016-01-13

In [503]: df.groupby("issue").agg({"p_date": "min", "s_date": "max"})
Out[503]: 
          p_date     s_date
issue                      
issue 2012-11-01 2016-01-13
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not happy with my answer but it seems to work.

I created a floor and ceiling dates.

```
floor = datetime.date ( 1900, 1, 1 )
ceil = datetime.date ( 2100, 1, 1 )

df_td [ 'p_date' ] = np.where ( df_td.action == '+', df_td.date, ceil )
df_td [ 's_date' ] = np.where ( df_td.action == '-', df_td.date, floor )
```

That way they will offset the min/max aggregate function that need a data object to work.

still would like a more appropriate suggestion.  Thanks.